# Javafx bind SetProperty to a callback that produce a set from an observable

Tags: java, javafx, observer-pattern

I have a `SetProperty<Point>` and a function that produces a `Stream<Point>`.

```
Stream<Point> generatePoints(Point p) {
    // ...
}
ObjectProperty<Point> selectedPointProperty() {
    // ...
}

SetProperty<Point> generatedPoints = new SimpleSetProperty();
```

I would like to bind `generatedPoints` to the result of applying `generatedPoints` to the result of `selectedPointProperty()`. I tried following code, but it has type error.

```
generatedPoints.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> generatePoints(selectedPointProperty().get()).collect(Collectors.toSet()),
 selectedPointProperty()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SetProperty<T>` is not a `Property<Set<T>>` but a `Property<ObservableSet<T>>`.

Therefore the type needed for the property and the type returned by

```
generatePoints(selectedPointProperty().get()).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

do not match. You need to return a `ObservableSet` from the `Callable` instead, e.g:

```
generatedPoints.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> FXCollections.observableSet(generatePoints(selectedPointProperty().get()).toArray(Point[]::new)),
        selectedPointProperty()));
```